# having problem while running a insert query using select query through php code

Tags: php, mysql

```
INSERT INTO `C301554_myroom`.`visitor` (
`Name` ,
`Address` ,
`City` ,
`State` ,
`Country` ,
`PIN` ,
`no_of_males` ,
`no_of_females` ,
`no_of_childrens` ,
`mail` ,
`Phone_no` ,
`Senior_Citizens` ,
`ID` ,
`date_from` ,
`date_to` ,
`Visitor_ID` ,
`Vehicle_No` ,
`Purpose`
)
VALUES (
'Jaspreet', 'D-66', 'Rohtak', 'HR', (

SELECT Country_Name
FROM country_code
WHERE Country_Code = "IN"
), '124001', '1', '1', '1', '', '2324342', 'Y', 'passport', '3/7/2011', '6/7/2011', 'null', '22', 'For Admission'
```

Above query is running on mysql but when i am trying to execute the query through php it is giving mysql error. 
-----here the code is------

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `C301554_myroom`.`visitor` (
`Name` ,
`Address` ,
`City` ,
`State` ,
`Country` ,
`PIN` ,
`no_of_males` ,
`no_of_females` ,
`no_of_childrens` ,
`mail` ,
`Phone_no` ,
`Senior_Citizens` ,
`ID` ,
`date_from` ,
`date_to` ,
`Visitor_ID`,
`Vehicle_No`,
`Purpose`
)

VALUES('$jName','$jAddress','$jCity','$jState',(select Country_Name from country_code where Country_Code=".$jcountry."),'$jpin','$jmale','$jfemale','$jchildren','$jemail','$jphone','$jSenior_Citizen','$jid','$jfrom','$jto','$RID','$jvehicle','$jpurpose')";
```

Comment: Please go back and format your code legibly.

Comment: echo $sql, probably a quote or other un-santised char

Comment: I think that `Country_Code` is string, so you should add quotes to `Country_Code='".$jcountry."'`

Comment: Country_Code should be quoted as its a string

Comment: i know where is the error when the subquery executes (select Country_Name from country_code where Country_Code=".$jcountry.") it will return a variable (for eg india) now to execute the whole query the value teturned(INDIA) should be in double quotes("INDIA") and i am unable to do that.How to concatenate double quotes with it.I tried it many times using . operator but still getting error

Comment: there is one more thing that i don't like. in your fisrt code snippet (sql-query) there is a syntax  Country_Code = "IN" which is incorrect. String constats are embrasing to single quotes Country_Code = 'IN'.

Comment: @heximal i agree with you actually i am using two letters country codes and for India it is IN and i know In is the keyword in mysql so it is giving error --insert query failedColumn 'Country' cannot be null-- please suggest me how can i resolve this without changing the country code

Answer (score 2):

You're missing single quotes around the `$jcountry` in the sub-query that select the country code.

```
(select Country_Name from country_code where Country_Code='".$jcountry."')
```

Comment: @Jaspreet Singh - Use prepared statements and you will no longer need to care about single quotes.